# WSO2 API Manager 1.4.0 Management Console

Tags: wso2

I downloaded and installed the WSO2 API Manager version 1.4.0 yesterday and I cannot login to the web management console `(https://localhost:9443/carbon)` using the default credentials (i.e. admin/admin)

I can login to the API store and API publisher and the error comes only for the management console.

Note that I performed the default install (unzip and ran ./wso2server.sh from the bin folder)

Following is part of the error stacktrace

```
2013-06-03 15:42:13,095]  INFO - CarbonAuthenticationUtil 'admin@carbon.super [-1234]' logged in at [2013-06-03 15:42:13,095+1000]

[2013-06-03 15:42:13,112] ERROR - AuthenticationHandler System error : 0 active authenticators registered in the system. The system should have at least 1 active authenticator service registered.
java.lang.RuntimeException: System error : 0 active authenticators registered in the system. The system should have at least 1 active authenticator service registered.
    at org.wso2.carbon.server.admin.module.handler.AuthenticationHandler.isAuthenticated(AuthenticationHandler.java:144)
    at org.wso2.carbon.server.admin.module.handler.AuthenticationHandler.authenticate(AuthenticationHandler.java:83)

Further down the stacktrace, I also get the below

[2013-06-04 11:42:15,860] ERROR - AxisEngine Authentication failure
org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: Authentication failure
    at org.wso2.carbon.server.admin.module.handler.AuthenticationHandler.authenticate(AuthenticationHandler.java:110)
    at org.wso2.carbon.server.admin.module.handler.AuthenticationHandler.invoke(AuthenticationHandler.java:55)
    at org.apache.axis2.engine.Phase.invokeHandler(Phase.java:340)
    at org.apache.axis2.engine.Phase.invoke(Phase.java:313)
```

I also get the following two warning messages on startup

```
[2013-06-04 11:14:05,489]  WARN - ValidationResultPrinter Swap Memory size (MB): 64 of the system is below the recommended minimum size :2048

[2013-06-04 11:14:15,444]  WARN - LandingPageWebappDeployer Product landing page not found.
```

Comment: Did you do any configuration changes?

Comment: No. I just unzipped it and then went into the bin folder and ran ./wso2server.sh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@nuwandias Hi Nuwan.

I identified the issue. When I was evaluating the previous 1.3.1 version, I injected the Authorization header with the Bearer token via my Firefox browser plugin.

That was what caused the problem with the 1.4.0 version. Once I disable it it works fine.

All good now and I am looking forward to doing a deep dive evaluation of this product.

Thanks a lot for your support.

Answer (score 0):

I have just downloaded the zip from the website and tried the same and it worked fine. Can you please provide the following information.

1. What is the environment that you are trying this on (OS)?
2. What is the md5sum value of the zip archive? Mine is fea68eaadd17daa5e6fa0aff3d973601.
3. Do you see any errors/warnings on startup? If so, could you share the startup logs too?

Thanks,
Nuwan.

Comment: Hi Nuwan, 1). Operating System : Mac OS X 10.8.3, x86_64 (Mac mountain lion), 2). its the same as yours, 3). No errors/warnings on startup.

Comment: Sorry refer to this comment and disregard my previous comment. 1). Operating System : Mac OS X 10.8.3, x86_64 - Mac mountain lion Java Version: 1.6.0_45 Java VM : Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 20.45-b01-451,Apple Inc., 2). its the same as yours, 3). I get two warning messages on startup. Refer to my edited question where I added the warning messages as well

Comment: please also note that this worked fine with the previous version 1.3.1

Answer (score 0):

Looking at this log message...

Swap Memory size (MB): 64 of the system is below the recommended minimum size :2048

It seems like your hard drive (or partition) has filled up. I'm wondering whether this could have caused any errors when you unzipped the zip file (if the hard disk has no free space).

If this is the case, can you free up some space (>200MB) in your partition, unzip the archive again and retry?

Comment: thank you for responding but I have over 130GB free on that drive with is btw an SSD drive.

Comment: I also tried it on another non SSD drive on the same computer which had over 400GB free and got the same error. I also have 16GB of ram on the machine. I will try it on a Win 7 machine today but was just wondering, is this working for you guys on Mac OS X 10.8.3? (mountain lion)

Comment: Hi Nuwan, I also just increased the Swap file size on my Mac machine to 2048MB and now I don't get that warning but I still cannot login to the management console.